# Getting unwanted characters while reading properties from application. Properties file

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, character-encoding

I am trying to read values from application  properties file.
It is working fine on local(windows machine) but when I deploy my code on aws I get some unwanted characters appended to the value of the variable e.g /n at the end of the the value.
I am using Springboot

We tried getting all the properties into a map on startup and logging them. We did not find any %0a character appended into the values. Here is the code snippet -

```
 Properties prop = new Properties();
    try(final InputStream stream =       
 Application.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application- 
    dev.properties")) {
        prop.load(stream);
        System.out.println(prop.values().toString());

        Set set = prop.entrySet();
        Iterator itr = set.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)itr.next();
            log.info("key as Normal String "+entry.getKey());
            log.info("key as URl Encoded "+ URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(entry.getKey()), String.valueOf(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));

            log.info("Value as Normal String "+entry.getValue());
            log.info("Value as URl Encoded "+ URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(entry.getValue()), String.valueOf(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
```

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: #application.properties - cloud.api.key = mhgtdfiyrezwxmbn. In my java file I am using it like this- @value{cloud.api.key} private String apiKey;  I am getting unwanted characters in the variable apiKey.

Comment: without more details, the best i can do is speculate.  my wild guess is that your properties file was made on windows and has windows line endings "\r\n" and that your aws image is linux (with line endings of "\n").  on linux the "\r" is not treated as a line ending and is being read as part of the variable.  if this is the case, then you should change the line endings of your properties file to linux style.

Comment: As updated in the question. We tried to print all the properties on application start up but did not found any issue. But when we use the @Value annotation to get the properties and URL encode it then it appends %0A in the value of the property

Comment: Is the line ending in the properties indeed `\r\n`? Sometimes there is an erroneous `\n\r` (%0a%0d) often introduced by code generation/regex replaces. In every case the annotation processing cannot seem to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

In your EC2 instance you need to add the `file.encoding` parameter and set to `UTF-8`.

We can pass this property using maven in the `jvmArguments`:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

Also, you can export as `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`:

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```